# ORA-01008: not all variables bound with bcrypt in Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle

So, I'm trying to encrypt the lastname ( just for testing) and it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```js
function getEmployeeFromRec(req) {

  let employee;
   bcrypt.hash(req.body.lastname, 10, (err, hash) => {
     employee = {
    id: req.body.id,
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: hash,
    datebirth: req.body.datebirth,
     }
  });
  return employee;
}
```

This is my SQL statement code:

```
const createSql =
 `insert into sys.test_table (
    id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    datebirth
  ) values (
    :id,
    :firstname,
    :lastname,
    :datebirth
  )`;

async function create(emp) {
  const employee = Object.assign({}, emp);

  const result = await database.simpleExecute(createSql, employee);

  return employee;
}
```

SimpleExecute() is doing the SqlStatement wih the data I put in it.

Here is my post code:

```
async function post(req, res, next) {
  try {
    let employee = getEmployeeFromRec(req);

    employee = await employees.create(employee);

    res.status(201).json(employee);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
}
```

I am a beginner so if you could give me also some new tips to learn, I would be grateful.
This is my first tutorial I worked with:
https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

EDIT:
I found the solution, thanks to nopassport1 for helping!

The new code:

```
function getEmployeeFromRec(req) {

  var employee;

  let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.lastname, 10);

    employee = {
    id: req.body.id,
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: hash,
    datebirth: req.body.datebirth,
     };
  return employee;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a little vague. What exactly doesn't work? Is your `hash` empty? Do you get any errors in your `err`? Have you tried debugging the issue?

Comment: Hello. I do not get any errors in `err`, and the SQL statement does not work. If I do not put the 'bcrypt', it works perfectly fine, but now I get that ORA error, and I really don't know what to do. The SQL statement is an INSERT INTO....

Comment: Can you update your question to include the SQL statement? And can you paste the ORA error as well please?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: The example code doesn't use `bcrypt` for a reason. https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/df67952d06822fe1ba7df0b0cf36111edc6788ac/javascript/rest-api/part-4-handling-post-put-and-delete-requests/hr_app/controllers/employees.js#L27 The reason it'll be failing is likely because your database doesn't recognise `lastname` as your `hash` variable. Or rather that the `hash` is not compatible with the type of `lastname`. Or that the value is too large for the field. Not sure. Simply hashing the variable will not work. You will need to update the rest of your application/ database

Comment: `lastname` is a varchar2(20 BYTE), but what can I do to encrypt it? Again, I am just a beginner and I am a little confused

Comment: Alright, what does your `employee` object include (inside your `create` method)? (without submitting the SQL statement)

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: I mean `console.log` this -> `employee` object `const employee = Object.assign({}, emp);`

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that your `hash` will look something like this: `$2y$10$mlsFPn5C/r9HzdJ.1fWXzOSb3yvSMMipGlw6TBVBJxgM1TsnXqfCG` - which is 60 characters. Which I don't think can be stored in a 20 byte field

Comment: So the `employee object` is empty ( {}) after the `bcrypt`.. So I understand that `bcrypt` does not work properly in my program.

Comment: Okay, that's good. Now you see where your issue is. Have you considered using `var` instead of `let` in your `getEmployeeFromRec`? Try to output the `employee` object within that function before you return - to see if you actually get the values you want.

Comment: I tried, but it's the same problem :/.

Comment: I tried without hash, and it worked perfectly , so yes, req contains the data.

Comment: I found the problem, thanks for the helping <3